# Using Facebook Graph API, get all pages liked by a certain user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'm using the following endpoint: /{user-id}/likes

but I keep receiving a single field called "data" with an empty list. I have tried many users that I saw they like some pages.

PD: I'm using the Facebook Graph Explorer

Comment: Users have to give your app permission first, before you can access their likes.

Comment: @CBroe even if the likes in the profile are public i.e. you can see them (with normal navigation, not API) without having them added as friends and no friends in common?

Comment: Yes. What you can access as a user via the UI, and what you can access via API, are two totally different things.

Comment: @CBroe would it be possible to code a browser extension that gets all the page likes of users while navigating through their profiles via the UI?

Comment: Probably ... but what do you need this for?

Comment: @CBroe I need it to get some statistics and maybe apply some machine learning in order to obtain tendencies over the people that commented a particular post.  With the extension I would have to go profile by profile scraping the data but I guess it can work if there is no better way

Comment: Ah, so exactly the thing Facebook does not want you to do ...

Comment: I didn't know that... I saw that some time ago you could do it by querying using fql or something like that so I was not sure if they deprecated it in order to enhance the process.